# From bitwise instructions to c code intuitively

Tags: c, assembly, code

I need to be able to recognize what an assembly code is doing. I can picture the basic instructions in C code in my head. But bitwise instructions such as `and 10000001` and `xor 11111111` in the middle of the code aren't so straightforward to comprehend.
Can someone explain how I should be intuitively translating bitwise operations to c code?
Thank you

Comment: Without context or specific example, it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried `& 0x81` or `^ 0xff` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignacio is spot-on in his comment, and I'll add that the hardware functionality is actually closer to the assembly code so it would be better to learn assembly directly rather than attempting to translate.

The particular examples you presented have direct C equivalents, but there are many assembly operations which do not (despite C's low-level emphasis), so you will quickly get into trouble if you approach it that way. For example, rotating the bits in a byte with or without a carry bit could be clumsy. I know this for a fact because I have translated tight microcontroller assembly code that I have written into C for simulation (eg. Fractional math calculations).

Compare to learning a different natural human language- you may have to embrace some different paradigms to become moderately fluent. In English we go forward into future which seems to makes sense until you realize there are other languages in which you go backwards- you can see what's behind but not what is to come.

You'll want to study the instruction set, of course, with emphasis on adressing modes as well as the functions, but also the programming model- registers and so on. There is much more variation from processor to processor than there is between flavors of 'C'.

Comment: I don't really doubt you, but which assembly-operations do you feel do not have direct C-equivalents?

Comment: @avl_sweden For example barrel shifting or BCD decimal adjustment.

Comment: @avl_sweden - Some already mentioned by Spehro - Rotate left/right, Rotate left/right including carry, And-Or-accumulate, Shift left/right with carry, Bit Test and Clear, Bit Test and Jump, Bit Test and Call -- There are too many old CPUs to think back and recall all of these.

Comment: HCF could be one.

Comment: Some modern C compilers will convert certain boolean and comparison operator combinations into bit operations, but there is no way to express them directly without depending on compiler features.

Comment: Good point! Had forgot about all that :-). Thank you.

Comment: @Sphro - HCF immediately came to mind but you had covered it. But HCF ~= HLL compile, or even git ... .